# an example on kinematical theory in the book "A treatise on the analytical dynamics of particles and rigid bodies"

Tags: classical-mechanics

In page 3, Example 1 says "A lamina moves in any manner in its plane. Prove that the locus at any instant of points which are at inflexions of their paths is a circle, which touches the loci in the lamina and in space of the center of instantaneous rotation."

Can anyone explain what the author asks me to prove?I cannot understand the exact meaning of the second long sentence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are asked (in 19th century English) to explain why all points on a lamina moving in a plane that are points of inflection (so have zero normal acceleration) lie on a circle. A more modern derivation is given, for example, on page 73 of [this text book.](https://books.google.nl/books?id=kLnfBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=inflection+circle+lamina&source=bl&ots=a12ALZ7Map&sig=vLq49GgZm0alKen-DEqfPn3K29A&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) The inflection circle touches the center of rotation, both when considered in a reference frame that is fixed in space and fixed in the lamina.

Comment: Carlo Beenakker: thank you! You answer and the book that you recommended perfectly settled my question.